# Checkstyle - methods order by modifier

Tags: java, gradle, code-formatting, checkstyle

Is it possible add to checkstyle rule to have ordered methods in class by modifier. I mean public methods on the begining and private methods in the end ?

Answer (score 1):

`MethodsOrderCheck` do this job.

Check the [documentation](https://www.qulice.com/qulice-checkstyle/apidocs-0.16.2/com/qulice/checkstyle/MethodsOrderCheck.html)

*FYI*: there is some logical [issue](https://github.com/teamed/qulice/issues/930) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle has a check for that called DeclarationOrderCheck - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/coding/DeclarationOrderCheck.html

You may find it in the 'Coding' group. Please tell me if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no :( It doesn't check methods modifiers

Comment: It doesn't check the methods modifiers

Answer (score -1):

You could use: `<module name="ModifierOrder"/>` that checks the order of modifiers.

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/modifier/ModifierOrderCheck.html