# Checkstyle Module for Method Ordering

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Is there a `Checkstyle` module that verifies that `public` methods should come before the `private` ones in a class? I can't find one.

`DeclarationOrderModifier` does not do it

`ModifierOrder` does not do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Checkstyle - methods order by modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457690/checkstyle-methods-order-by-modifier)

Answer (score 2):

*Updated*

`MethodsOrderCheck` can handle this.

See documentation here: [sourceforge link](https://www.qulice.com/qulice-checkstyle/apidocs-0.16.2/com/qulice/checkstyle/MethodsOrderCheck.html)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It checks the order of modifier - for example, public static final A is correct but static final public is not.

Comment: @PrashantPandey have you tried this: [MethodsOrderCheck](https://www.qulice.com/qulice-checkstyle/apidocs-0.8/com/qulice/checkstyle/MethodsOrderCheck.html) ?

Comment: This is from a third-party tool called "Qulice" (which I don't know), not normal Checkstyle.

Comment: Yes. Most probably it won't be approved at my workplace. May be I'll copy the code and create my own artifact.

Comment: I just checked the [open issues](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues), search for future "new check" to fulfill this need, but i cannot find one :(